# Keep white space in files after saving with HTML Simple Dom Parser

Tags: php, domparser

I am using 'PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser' to upload files (in this case a zip), open the index file, and allow for links to be changed. Once links are updated, the index file is overwritten and zipped up for download.

This all works fine, the only issue I am having is once the updated index file is saved, it loses all its white space within the file. So if you open the file in a text editor, it is no longer laid out with any structure so it is very difficult to read/edit normally.

Is there a way I can preserve this white space?

The "upload" file that takes the uploaded file, display it in an iFrame with fields below it to show existing links, and a field to update them:

```
       <div class="output">
        <form action="download.php" id="urlform" method="POST">

        <?php 

            //Traverse DOM of iFrame content, output existing href tags
            $html = file_get_html($_SESSION['index']);
            $i = 1;
            $inc = 1;

            foreach($html -> find('a') as $element) : ?>

                <!-- Ignore untagged links -->
                <?php if (strpos($element -> href, "utm") !== false) { 

                    $element -> name = $inc; ?>

                    <?php if ($i % 2 === 0) {
                        echo '<div class="alternate">';
                    } else {
                        echo '<div class="standard">';
                    } ?>

                    <!-- Add name attr to anchor tags for reference -->
                    <div class="assign">
                        <p><?php echo $element -> name; ?></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="content">

                        <h3>Existing tag:</h3>

                        <p><?php echo $element -> href; ?></p>

                        <h3>New tag:</h3> 

                        <input type="textarea" name="urltag_<?php echo $inc; ?>">

                        </div>

                    </div>

                <?php  $i++; $inc++; } ?>

           <?php endforeach; ?>


        <input type="submit" value="Update eShot">

    </form>
  </div>
```

And the download file, which shows an iFrame with the updated index file and a download:

```
<?php 
        //Open index.html of zip and replace href with new tags
        $newhtml = file_get_html($_SESSION['index']);

        $inc = 1;

        foreach($newhtml -> find('a') as $url) {

            if (strpos($url -> href, "utm") !== false) {

                $url -> href = $_POST["urltag_" . $inc];
                $inc++;
                };

            }

        //Store changes in new index file            
        file_put_contents($_SESSION['index'], $newhtml);

        $folder = $_SESSION['new_directory'];

        if (isset($_SESSION['portal'])){
            $zipname =  $_SESSION['name'] . " " . $_SESSION['portal'] . " " . date('dmy') . ".zip";
        } else {
            $zipname =  $_SESSION['name'] . " " . date('dmy') . ".zip"; 
        }


        class FlxZipArchive extends ZipArchive {

            public function addDir($folder, $zipname) {
                $this->addEmptyDir($zipname);

                $this->addDirDo($folder, $zipname);
             } 


            private function addDirDo($folder, $zipname) {
                $zipname .= '/';
                $folder .= '/';


                $dir = opendir ($folder);
                while ($file = readdir($dir))
                {
                    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;

                    $do = (filetype( $folder . $file) == 'dir') ? 'addDir' : 'addFile';
                    $this->$do($folder . $file, $zipname . $file);
                }
            } 
        }

        $za = new FlxZipArchive;
        $res = $za->open($folder . "/" . $zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
        if($res === TRUE) 
        {
            $za->addDir($folder, basename($folder));
            $za->close();
        }
        else  { echo 'Could not create a zip archive';}

    ?>


    <div class="thankyou">
        <p>Thank you. Please check your new links in the eShot below:</p>
    </div>

    <iframe class="eshotwrapper" src="<?php echo $_SESSION['index'] ?>"></iframe>

    <div class="downloadlink">
        <p>Once you have confirmed your tagged links are correct, please click the link below to download your new eShot: <br>
            (Right-click and select "Save as..." to choose a save location)</p>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SESSION['new_directory'] . "/" . $zipname ?>"><button type="button">Download</button></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you parse the HTML into a DOM tree, then the original formatting is not maintained in that structure at all.  However, you could run the output through a library to put in proper indentation and beautify the output.

If you want to maintain the output exactly as-is, you'll have more success using regexes to find and wrap tags.